# What analysis to use for ABA study design with repeated measures

Tags: regression, predictive-models, paired-data

I have a data set of ~50 subjects including demographic data, such as age, gender, employment, education, and the presence or absence of a health condition. 
Study Design looks like the following:

- Day 1 the participants took tests A thru E one after another two different times that day and test F once 2 hours before tests A-E.
- Day 2: same as day one
- Day 3: all of the subjects received the treatment and took took tests A-E 4 different times throughout the day and test F once.
- Day 4: all of the subjects received the treatment and took took tests A-E 4 different times throughout the day and test F once.
- Day 5: same as day one

I would like to:

1. Compare the effect of the treatment as measured by pre/post intervention scores on the 6 tests.
2. Utilize the pre-intervention scores of one or more of tests A-E to predict the final, post-intervention score of test F
3. Compare which test or combination of tests A-E best correlated with the score of test F throughout the entire study
4. Examine how the health status and demographic characteristics influence the above analyses

I appreciate your advice.  (I plan to use SPSS as that is what I have experience with)